# How to get rid of '\u0002', '\r\n', and '\u0003' from string?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

How to strip string to get clean `7A005AFA518B`? Now on init it returns bitstring and it seems that strip doesn't work for it. I've tried to use pattern matching to get string from start text unicode "\u0002" to end "\u0003" and then strip, but without success.

```
str = "\u00027A005AFA518B\r\n\u0003"
String.codepoints(String.strip(str))
[<<2>>, "7", "A", "0", "0", "5", "A", "F", "A", "5", "1", "8", "B", "\r", "\n",
 <<3>>]
```

I found that `String.split(str, "\r\n")` do this job but maybe is it cleaner way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String.strip`, `String.lstrip` and `String.rstrip` strip whitespace by default, but take a `char` code as second parameter. The `\u0002` (start of text) and `\u0003` (end of text) characters have the codes `2` and `3` respectively. So you could do it like this, while preserving unicode characters etc:

```
str = "\u00027A005AFA518B\r\n\u0003"

str |> String.lstrip(2) |> String.rstrip(3) |> String.strip
#=> "7A005AFA518B"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    Enum.filter(to_char_list(str), &(&1 > 32 && &1 < 122))
```

Like a solution to get clear string

Comment: Note that this will discard most unicode characters. It also returns a character list, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the [replace](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/String.html#replace/4) function :

`IO.puts String.replace(String.replace(str,"\u0003",""),"\u0002","")`

Answer (score -2):

You can use org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.trim(String str)

Comment: are talking about `java`?

Comment: Sorry. I did not notice the OP was asking about Elixir.